# Exibir json em diferentes locais do meu html estatico

Tags: javascript, html, css

Olá tenho um json : http://mulher.store/clara/admin/api/empresa.php?e=8

os dados dessa api precisam aparecer em locais diversos da minha pagina html: exemplo:

```
<div id="community-members-member-top-title" class="empresas">
<h1> Hotel Sol Y Luna</h1>
<p class="page-text9">Fundo Huincho Lote A5</p>
</div>
```

essas duas tags consegui alterar... mas barrei nas imagens...

```
<script>
        fetch("http://mulher.store/clara/admin/api/empresa.php?e=8").then((answer) => {
            answer.json().then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                const empresas = document.querySelector(".empresas");
                li = document.createElement("h1");
                li.innerHTML = `
                     <p>${response.empresa.nome}</p>                  
                    `;
                empresas.append(li);
                const pagetext9 = document.querySelector(".page-text9");
                li = document.createElement("p");
                li.innerHTML = `
                     <p>${response.empresa.endereco}</p>                  
                    `;
                pagetext9.append(li);
            });
        });
    </script>
<script>
        const baseURL = `http://mulher.store/clara/admin/api/empresa.php?e=8`;
        fetch(baseURL).then((answer) => {
            answer.json().then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                const imagens = response.fotos.map((foto) => {
                    return `
            <img src="https://remmote.la/img/community/${foto.url}" alt="fotos" />
              `;
                });
                const galeria = document.querySelector(".galeria");
                li = document.createElement("picture");
                li.innerHTML = `
                    <picture>
                       ${imagens}
                    </picture>
                    `;
                galeria.append(li);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

html imagens:

```
<div class="community-members-member-content-gallery-imgs-img-inner-inner">
<picture class="galeria">
<p class="galeria-fotos"></p>
<picture>
                    <picture>
```

porem a imagem não carrega

link: mulher.store/clara/tiago

Comment: acho que seria mais fácil fazer o fetch uma única vez e guardar numa variável, assim por exemplo `const dados = fetch('http://mulher.store/clara/admin/api/empresa.php?e=8');` e depois usar a variável "dados" onde precisar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Mesmo já tendo uma resposta aceita, vou deixar um exemplo com outra abordagem, sem a necessidade de conversão do **`array`**, o que acho totalmente desnecessário, além de mais algumas correções!

Como comentado pelo Ricardo, vc está repetindo a mesma chamada ao mesmo endpoint desnecessariamente, ou vc guarda o retorno em uma `variável/constante` (indicado se ficar grande o código, podendo particionar o mesmo em funções), ou faz tudo dentro do mesmo **`fetch`** como fiz no exemplo. Como pode ver no mesmo não há necessidade de conversão do array utilizando **join('')**, vc simplesmente pode percorre-lo e fazer a lógica que precisa lá dentro.

```js
const baseURL = `http://mulher.store/clara/admin/api/empresa.php?e=8`;
const empresas = document.querySelector('.empresas');
const galeria = document.querySelector('.galeria');

fetch(baseURL).then((answer) => {
  answer.json().then((response) => {
    
    const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    h1.innerHTML = `
       <span>${response.empresa.nome}</span>                  
    `;
    empresas.append(h1);
    
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = `
       <span>${response.empresa.endereco}</span>                  
    `;
    empresas.append(p);

    // IMAGENS
    response.fotos.map((foto) => {
      const picture = document.createElement('picture');
      picture.innerHTML = `
         <img src="https://remote.la/img/community/${foto.url}" alt="Fotos" />
      `;
      galeria.append(picture);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="community-members-member-top-title" class="empresas"></div>


<div class="community-members-member-content-gallery-imgs-img-inner-inner">
  <p class="galeria-fotos">IMAGENS</p>
  <div class="galeria"></div>
</div>
```

**OBS:**

> Para acessar elementos do DOM é melhor já acessá-los quando no carregamento da página, ou seja, fora do **`fetch`**

> Quando da criação de elementos no DOM, é indicado utilizar uma variável/constante senão aquele elemento ficará global no código, como aqui: `li = document.createElement("h1");`

> Vc utilizou a mesma referência na memória para criar elementos diferentes, como aqui `li = document.createElement("h1");` e logo depois aqui `li = document.createElement("p");`

> Como dito na outra resposta, a **url** das imagens está incorreta.

Comment: LeAndrade, muito obrigado por sua explicação, vou aplicar e ver o resultado!

Comment: Funcionou muito Bem LeAndrade.. agora é só eu aplicar um css para coloca-las lado a lado?

Comment: Isso mesmo, pode utilizar flexbox se precisar: https://origamid.com/projetos/flexbox-guia-completo/

Answer (score 0):

São 2 problemas:

O primeiro é que o código está colocando uma vírgula depois de cada imagem. Isso porque a variável imagens é um array, e não uma string.
Para resolver, troque `${imagens}` por `${imagens.join('')}`.

O segundo problema é no seu servidor. Ele está retornando a URL errada das imagens.
Você está pegando elas do site remote.la, mas o servidor entrega a URL com remmote.la (com 'm' repetido).

Comment: Bah andre, show de bola, deu certinho...  uma outra duvida, ele esta inserindo uma em cima da outra, no html estatico eu tinha uma div para cada imagem, sera que consigo recuperar essas do servidor e fazer a mesma coisa para que eu possa fazer uma galeria?

Comment: Sim! Vai precisar trocar o código de `const galeria = ...` pra baixo.
O que você quer é encontrar a div mãe, e inserir nela as outra divs, com a mesma estrutura de cada slide.